# Cannot get data from SQL PhP, returns page unable to handle request

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PhP and I'm trying to make a staff portal with permissions. When I try and fetch data from my table, the page returns "unable to handle this request". Any help is appreciated, here's what I've tried.

```
<?php
include('./classes/Login.php');
if (Login::isLoggedIn()) {
        $userid = Login::isLoggedIn();
        $staff = "true";
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","mqefjvgt_portal","-password sniped-","mqefjvgt_portal");
        $radiodj_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT is_radio FROM users_permissions WHERE id=$userid;");
        if ( $radiodj_query == "1" ){
                $radiodj = "true";
                $staff = "true";

        }
        $media_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT is_media FROM users_permissions WHERE id=$userid;");
        if ( $media_query == "1" ){
                $media = "true";
                $staff = "true";
        }
        $management_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT is_management FROM users_permissions WHERE id=$userid;");
        if ( $management_query == "1" ){
                $management = "true";
                $staff = "true";
        }
        $admin_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT is_admin FROM users_permissions WHERE id=$userid;");
        if ( $admin_query == "1" ){
                $admin = "true";
                $staff = "true";
        }
        $owner_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT is_owner FROM users_permissions WHERE id=$userid;");
        if ( $owner_query == "1" ){
                $owner = "true";
                $staff = "true";
        }
        echo $owner_query;
        echo $admin_query;
        echo $management_query;
        echo $media_query;
        echo $radiodj_query;
} else {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='login.php'\" />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why one query for each column on the same table with the same criteria? You can select more than one column at a time `SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE id=$userid;`

Comment: Also, once you Query a table, you then have to FETCH the result [Please read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: This should help you understand whats going wrong here. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.